# Merging trunc to branch and back again

Tags: svn, merge

I have a problem merging from trunk to my branch.

I created the branch from a working copy of the trunk bu creating a new directory in the branches area (@ 4797) and copying the contents of the wc into it (@ 4798)

Now that I have finished my fix (@ 4832) I want to get all the changes from the trunk (@ 4836) into my branch before I reintegrate.

The problem is that svn tries to merge from the head of the development

```
svn merge .../trunk/app .
--- Merging r2487 through r4837 into '.'
```

Subsequently, merging from branch back to trunk, subversion doesn't recognise any relationship between the branch and the trunk so `--reintegrate` can't be applied.

I am using svn 1.6

Is there a way to sort this out? Do I have to go back to the old style of merge?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
svn merge -r 4797:HEAD .../trunk/app .
```